# Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-11"

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

My java application was running fine, but now only some functionality of it throws this error

```
Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-11" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:587)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:214)
 at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:575)
```

functionalities are add campaign and delete campaign. When i try to add a campaign or delete a campaign this error is thrown.
Theres option of adding keywords in each campaign, that is running fine. and also other parts of application is running fine.

code snippet of the delete campaign service

```
   public String deleteSerpsCampaign() {
    objRequest = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

    //initializing http session object
    objSession = objRequest.getSession();

    //checking for 'customerID' attribute in session
    if (objSession.getAttribute("customerID") != null) {
        Integer campaignId = 0;
        campaignId = Integer.parseInt(jString);
        System.out.println("Site id is:::" + campaignId);

        //reading the 'customerID' from session and type casting it to integer
        Integer customerID = (Integer) objSession.getAttribute("customerID");

        //now invoking the deleteCampaign() method of CampaignsServiceImpl
        String campaignName = objCampaignsService.deleteCampaign(campaignId, customerID);
        message = "'" + campaignName + "' - Campaign has been Deleted";
        objSession.setAttribute("message", message);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    //if session attribute 'customerID' is null then return result parameter as 'LOGIN'
    //this result parameter is mapped in 'struts.xml'
    return LOGIN;
}
```

deleteCampaign method

```
   public String deleteCampaign(Integer campaignId, Integer customerID) {
    int delCount = 0;
    Campaigns objcamp = (Campaigns) getSession().get(Campaigns.class, campaignId);
    try {
        Collection objserpkeywords = objcamp.getSerpkeywordsCollection();
        Iterator itr = objserpkeywords.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Serpkeywords objserpkeys = (Serpkeywords) itr.next();
            if (objserpkeys.getVisibility() == 1) {
                delCount++;
                objserpkeys.setVisibility(0);
                getSession().update(objserpkeys);
            }
        }
        Collection objseokeywords = objcamp.getSeokeyworddetailsCollection();
        Iterator ittr = objseokeywords.iterator();
        while (ittr.hasNext()) {
            Seokeyworddetails objseokeys = (Seokeyworddetails) itr.next();
            if (objseokeys.getVisibility() == 1) {
                objseokeys.setVisibility(0);
                getSession().update(objseokeys);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        String sQuery = "update campaigns set visibility=0 where CampaignID=:campaignId";
        SQLQuery objQuery = getSession().createSQLQuery(sQuery);
        objQuery.setParameter("campaignId", campaignId);
        objQuery.executeUpdate();
    } catch (DataAccessResourceFailureException | IllegalStateException | HibernateException ex) {
        l.error(ex + "  " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    Customers objCustomers = (Customers) getSession().get(Customers.class, customerID);
    try {
        objCustomers.setActiveSerpCampaignsCount(objCustomers.getActiveSerpCampaignsCount() - 1);
        objCustomers.setActiveKeywordCount(objCustomers.getActiveKeywordCount() - delCount);
        getSession().update(objCustomers);
    } catch (DataAccessResourceFailureException | IllegalStateException | HibernateException ex) {
        l.error(ex + "  " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return objcamp.getCampaign();
}
```

Comment: Please Some help. I am new to this issue. I have already added this:
UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Comment: Add the issue doesnt seem of adding UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m because the issue is in server too

Comment: You are running out of memory when generating the JSON reply: "at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:575)". Maybe the object being serialized to JSON contains circular dependencies?

Comment: var alertMes = "";
    function addSerpsCampaign() {
        var jString = document.addserpform.campaignName.value + ":" + document.addserpform.url.value;
        $.post(
                'ajax/addSerpsCampaign.action',
                {
                    jString: jString
                },
        function (jMessage) {
            alertMes = jMessage.message;
            if (alertMes === "Campaign Value required") {
                window.location = "serps.action";
                document.addserpform.campaignName.focus();
            } 
        },
                'json');
    }

Comment: in the above way we hitting the action in jsp

Comment: in struts.xml we are configuring the action class like this
 <action name="addvioCampaign" class="com.auditmysite.action.VideoTrackAction" method="addVideoCampaign">
            <result type="json" >
                <param name="excludeProperties">
                    objCampaignsService
                </param>
            </result>
        </action>

Comment: All that info is of no use in the matter. You have a java Object that is being converted to JSON. It is in that point that you are running out of memory. My suggestion is that you look at your objects and see if it has circular dependencies that would cause an infinite loop in the conversion.

Comment: actually error is thrown after the service returns success, and anways there is no such conversion in java class as you can see

Comment: at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:575)